# Do the Babylon 5 'command staff' know each other prior to serving on B5?

Tags: babylon-5

I am re-watching Babylon 5 and noticed that there is a lot of familiarity between the command staff even when they have supposedly first met.

Is it ever explained if and how Sinclair, Sheridan, Garibaldi, Ivanova and Franklin and the other Babylon 5 staff knew each other before serving on the station?

Comment: Sinclair and Garibaldi go a long way back. Sinclair and Sheridan both are kind of legendary, with one "winning" the unwinnable Battle of the Line and the other doing the similarly miraculous destruction of a Minbari Sharlin class (the flagship *Drala Fi* no less). Franklin is the son of a General, so his name is well known around Earth Force as well. Ivanonva and Sheridan served together on Io years before meeting again on B5. So yeah.. apparently, it's a small galaxy :P (Getting even smaller once Lochley comes abord, who was of course once married to Sheridan.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Sheridan and Sinclair** knew each other, having served together on Mars some ten years before serving together on B5.

> **Sinclair:** *Good to see you again.*
>
> **Sheridan:** *I'll be.*
>
> **Sinclair:** *And you.*
>
> **Sheridan:** *I haven't seen you since the Mars riots.*
>
> <sub><sup>War Without End, Part I</sup></sub>

**Ivanova and Sheridan** knew each other having served together near Earth-space after the Earth/Minbari War.

> **Ivanova:** *Capt. Sheridan. John Sheridan?*
>
> **Garibaldi:** *That's right. I believe you know him.*
>
> **Ivanova:** *Yes, I served under him at the transfer point off Io.*
>
> <sub><sup>Points of Departure</sup></sub>

**Garibaldi and Sheridan** did not know each other.

> **Sheridan:** *John Sheridan, your new CO.*
>
> **Garibaldi:** *I don't know you.*
>
> **Sheridan:** *No, but I think we'll get along just fine.*
>
> <sub><sup>Revelations</sup></sub>

**Franklin and Sheridan** knew each other. They'd both been part of a negotiating team *during* the Earth/Minbari war.

> **Sheridan:** *Anyone else on my team?*
>
> **LEFCOURT:** *Just one*.
>
> [beat]
>
> **LEFCOURT:** *Commander Sheridan, Dr. Stephen Franklin. He's had a fair amount of physical contact with the Minbari before the war. He
> can verify these individuals are who they say they are...*
>
> <sub><sup>B5: In the Beginning</sup></sub>

**Zack and Sinclair** didn't know each other prior to serving on B5

> **Sinclair:** *It's Zack, isn't it? Yes, sir.*
>
> **Zack:** *I came aboard just before you were promoted.*
>
> <sub><sup>War Without End, Part I</sup></sub>

We get a bit more info about Sinclair's relationship with Garibaldi in the (canon) comic [B5: Shadows Past and Present #1 - With Freinds Like These](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/With_Friends_Like_These). Apparently they met a year or so after the Mars Food Riots. Garibaldi and Sinclair went on a rescue mission, saved each other's lives a few times and became fast friends.

[image]

Comment: Is there any backstory other then throw away lines like this dotted throughout the show, any books or comics that go into more detail?

Comment: @RichardC - There's some stuff in the novels. They're not very good though.

Comment: @Valorum Any in the canon novels? As I recall, most of them are non-canon.

Comment: @Thunderforge - I don't think there's much more in the novels that isn't already covered in the films and TV series.

Comment: @Thunderforge  - At least about the characters mentioned.

Comment: @RichardC Not sure If this is what you’re looking for, but the S1 episode Babylon Squared shows a flashback to Garibaldi arguing with his then girlfriend on Mars about about he’s leaving for B5 because Sinclair, a guy who he’s met only a couple of times, asked him too. His relationship with her is mentioned here and there through the series and plays a bigger role in later seasons.